# Lightroom: Removing gray border around snapshots in GridView

Tags: lightroom

In Grid View in Lightroom I can see and modify the order of photographies so I can imagine how they will look like when I print and hang them on a wall.

[image: sample]

However, I cannot find any option to remove gray border around photos in Grid View. Is there a way to do it? If not, is there an alternative mode in Lightroom to play with photography sets?

Answer (score 1):

**L**

Press the `L` key. This puts Lightroom into *Lights Out* mode. Once it makes everything around the grid darker, twice it makes everything black and once more it goes back to grey. Lightroom features remain functional while in *Lights Out* mode.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to play with arranging photos would be by using the **Book Module**.